# How do I initiate the object state on its creation?

Tags: java

In this example, how do I initiate the object state on as soon as it's created?

```
public class Account {
    private double balance;

    public void credit(double amount){
        balance = balance + amount;
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just create a constructor taking the parameters, and set the values inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a simple constructor, as follows:

```
public class Account {
    private double balance;

    public Account(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public void credit(double amount){
            balance = balance + amount;
    }

    public double getBalance(){
            return balance;
    }
 }
```

From the method that creates an `Account` instance (e.g., from your `main` method), you can simply call this constructor as follows:

```
Account account = new Account(100.5);
```

to initialize an `Account` instance with a `balance` value of 100.5.

This is one of the first things that you should know when learning to program in Java, so perhaps an introductory book to Java would be highly recommended. It is the fastest way to learn Java, IMHO.